# How to grow a spirulina biofilm on a carbon/graphite cylindrical cathode?

Tags: microbiology, algae, biofilms, aquaculture

I am trying to grow a spirulina biofilm on my cathode for a fuel cell but it doesn't seem to be sticking to the cathode. I have a culture of spirulina  and I've submerged a few cathodes in it to try and develop a biofilm. This is not working. Is there anything I can do to promote spirulina growth on my cathode like coating it in glucose or something?

Comment: I keep finding articles that say Spirulina Platensis actually inhibits biofilms. Research is underway to use this property of Spriulina Platensis to disrupt the biofilms that protect pathogenic bacteria from antibiotics.